# Get String, Split By delimiter and inset to table Procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have ***Names*** table , ***z_names_seq*** sequence for AutoGenerate `ID`s (in `names` table) and Trigger **z_names_on_insert** that uses `z_names_seq`  for Generate `ID`.

--Create Names Table

```
CREATE TABLE z_names (ID number,
                      NAME VARCHAR2(200))
```

--Sequence For Names Table

```
CREATE SEQUENCE z_names_seq
    MINVALUE 1
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1;
```

--Trigger For ID In Names Table

```
create or replace TRIGGER z_names_on_insert
    BEFORE INSERT ON z_names
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT z_names_seq.nextval
    INTO :new.ID
    FROM dual;
END;
```

**AND Whats The Question:**

Write the procedure that gets string value, separate it by delimiter and insert into *z_names* table (`ID` comes from trigger and `NAME` comes from input string split by comma ( `,` )).

**Example Of Input and output:**

input :     `john, jim, jack`

output:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | john |
| 2 | jim |
| 3 | jack |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string into rows. Here's one option which shows how to do that. `INSERT` doesn't contain the `ID` column as it is populated by a trigger.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_ins (par_string in varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    insert into z_names (name)
  4      select trim(regexp_substr(par_string, '[^,]+', 1, level))
  5        from dual
  6        connect by level <= regexp_count(par_string, ',') + 1;
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_ins('john,jim,jack');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From z_names;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 john
         2 jim
         3 jack

SQL>
```